# ViewModel data not being found

Tags: c#, mvvm

My project ViewModel elements are not being found. I'm trying to implement a ViewModel within my WPF Usercontrol.  However, the binding isn't working properly and there appears to be no data.  I'm trying to create a ViewModel to interact with, putting generic string arrays into, and various other bits of data.

MainWindow.xaml - (Usercontrol declaration)

```
<panels:FilterLister Grid.Column="0" x:Name="filter1FilterLister" />
```

MainWindows.cs - (Within the constructor, call to usercontrol

```
filter1FilterLister.Initialise(typeof(Genre));
```

FilterListViewModel.cs

```
public class FilterListViewModel
{
    MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
    ObservableCollection<string> entries = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public Type SelectedType;
    private string p_TypeName;
    public string TypeName
    {
        get { return p_TypeName; }
        set { 
            //p_TypeName = value; 
            p_TypeName = SelectedType.Name.ToString();
        }
    }

    public FilterListViewModel() { }

    public FilterListViewModel(Type selectedType)
    {
        if (selectedType == typeof(Artist))
        {
            returnedArray = Artist.ReturnArtistNames(context);
        }

        // put together ObservableCollection
        foreach (var str in returnedArray)
        {
            entries.Add(str);
        }

        SelectedType = selectedType;
    }
}
```

FilterLister.xaml

```
<Label Name="labelToBind" Content="{Binding TypeName}" Grid.Row="0" />
```

FilterLister.cs

```
public partial class FilterLister : UserControl
{
    FilterListViewModel filterListViewModel;
    private MyEntities context;

    public FilterLister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new MyEntities();
    }

    public void Initialise(Type objectType)
    {
        filterListViewModel = new FilterListViewModel(objectType);
        this.DataContext = filterListViewModel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, TypeName is null so you saw nothing on the Label. From your code, I think you want to describe like:

```
public string TypeName
{
   get{ return SelectedType.Name.ToString();}
}
```

As deryck suggested, you should add INotifyPropertyChanged interface for notification, but it should not affect binding at first time. If you believe ViewModel's data is correct but not populated on UI, you should check DataContext and Binding.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel, it's needed to the binded property can send "refresh message" to a UI.

Here is the interface, and how you can implement this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

```
    public class FilterListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
ObservableCollection<string> entries = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public Type SelectedType;
private string p_TypeName;
public string TypeName
{
    get { return p_TypeName; }
    set { 
        //p_TypeName = value; 
        p_TypeName = SelectedType.Name.ToString();
  NotifyPropertyChanged();

    }
}

public FilterListViewModel() { }

public FilterListViewModel(Type selectedType)
{
    if (selectedType == typeof(Artist))
    {
        returnedArray = Artist.ReturnArtistNames(context);
    }

    // put together ObservableCollection
    foreach (var str in returnedArray)
    {
        entries.Add(str);
    }

    SelectedType = selectedType;
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
```